# Variable reference in php

Tags: php, reference

The output of this PHP code is `33`.

```
$b=2;
$a=&$b;
$a=3;
print $a;
print $b;
```

How did `$b` become 3?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Yes, yes, you should go through the php.net site's explanation on references. There are lot more interesting things. You would love references after reading it.

Comment: $b is not "real" variable and has no value but it is pointer to value of variable $a. When You output $b in reality You output value of $a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$a=&$b;` this line is like saying "from now on $b, you are also $a."

```
print $a; // prints 3
print $b; // prints another 3
```

Answer (score 4):

As `$a` is pointing to the `$b` memory location.

Now if you change value of `$a` it will actually update `$b` value (where the `$b` is stored). As both are pointing to the same memory location.

OR you can say `$a` and `$b` are the two different way to access the same memory location as you've assigned reference of `$b` to `$a`.

Answer (score 3):

[image: References in php]

As you can see from the above image , when you assign a reference of a variable to another variable then they both point to same location ,thus changes made by one reflect to other as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are sotring the "$b's address into the $a,and after that $a is changed,so that the value in the $b's address have changed and thus $b also changed

Answer (score 1):

Once you make a reference `$a` and `$b` are two names for the same variable.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php (Specifically first article in the list)